# C#, Compress directory with files opened for other applications

Tags: c#, directory, compression, zip

I'm working in a very basic C# application, I want to compress a directory that has some files (specifically a dbf database) that are already opened or in use for other software.

I use the class "ZipFile" in this way:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(source, path);
```

And I get an exception that says that It could not access to the file because it was already in use for other application.

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Windows does not allow most file access when the file has a write handle already open on it...   Your best bet is to stop the process and do your backup (assuming that's what it is), then start it again.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I just wanted to know if there was another solution but I see this is the only thing I can do, Thank you again.